# Liturgy of "The" hours

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Just noticed that the tag [liturgy-of-hours](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liturgy-of-hours) is missing the the, that's kind of confusing, I don't think it's going to mess anyone up necessarily, but it looks weird.

Also, could use synonyms with [breviary](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breviary), [divine-office](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divine-office), and [book-of-common-prayer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-of-common-prayer) (unless that overlaps another denomination's prayer book name, if it matters)

I don't think it would make sense to have multiple tags for all these.

Comment: I think it is common practice to omit "the" and other articles from tags. I can't speak to the rest. But we have `john-the-baptist` and others, so I'm fine with a change.

Comment: I thought that when I asked the question I presume you're referring to! And yes, I think having [tag:breviary] and [tag:divine-office] as synonyms would be sensible. [tag:book-of-common-prayer] would more normally refer to the Church of England prayer book rather than the LOTH.

Comment: @lonesomeday At your suggestion I have removed the tag synonym for book-of-common-prayer but left the other two intact.

Answer (score 5):

All better now.

<sub>Some rambling to reach the character limit....</sub>

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: @Wikis Exactly what the question called for: adding 'the' to the tag and creating synonyms.